# Einstein light clock?

Tags: special-relativity

In light clock thought experiment,if the observer is moving with velocity v relative to the light source&mirror frame ,then why path of light bends?
According to einstein's postulate speed of light is independent of source motion??

Comment: I think your question differs from the one refered to above as already answered.
"Light clock" (in that didactic set-up)  is, I think,  restricted to the observer carrying the time clock. As there  is "The" observer outside of the moved  frame(s),  i.e. you always have a third person who the torch is being waived to... (in other words: the one who the clock is being moved to "knows" it all, the others do not really know what they are doing, their space looks curved; sorry for elaborating, glad to set up some answer).

Answer (score 0):

> .... why path of light bends? According to einstein's postulate speed of light is independent of source motion??

Because "bending" is a second order notion. You have to know at least the second order terms of a function's Taylor series to know whether it is linear or nonlinear. You can't tell whether a function is nonlinear if you measure its changes over a subdomain wherein a linear approximation is better than your measurement accuracy.

On the other hand, the constancy of $c$ is a local notion; it says that, as long as your measurements are made in a domain with small enough extent in space and time that the spacetime manifold is well approximated by its tangent space, *i.e.* approximated by the best fit Minkowski spacetime approximation than to within a deviation smaller than your measurements can detect, then the maximum speed of propagation of a signal, or the speed of propagation of any massless particle (such as one of light), will be $c$.

You have to measure over a spacetime domain broad enough that the second derivatives of the metric can be detected to detect bending of light. Indeed, if one chooses so called Riemann normal co-ordinates, one can write the metric in terms of the Riemann tensor as:

$$g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{3} R_{i\,k\,j\,\ell} X^k\,X^\ell + O(X^3)$$

where $\eta = \mathrm{diag}(1,-1,-1,-1)$ is the Minkowski metric and our local laboratory is the same as Minkowski spacetime, to first order in the tangent vector (approximating the displacement from the origin) $X$. This equation gives yet another intuition for the Riemann tensor, as a fundamental "encoding" of the lowest order non-Minkowski behavior of the spacetime manifold.

Answer (score 0):

Only the speed of light is constant in special relativity , so the direction can be affected by the motion of the source.